# /etc/ppp/ip-up file is not being called upon VPN creation; Monterey

Tags: mac, bash, monterey

I'm trying to add certain subnets to my route table after launching an IKEv2 VPN tunnel from my Mac. I understand that this behaviour can be achieved by placing an executable `ip-up` file in `/etc/ppp/` folder.

File perms are correct it has 0755 and root is the owner, however upon firing up the VPN tunnel the route is not being added. I suspect the file is not being called?

Contents of the `ip-up` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/route add -net 192.168.66.0/24 -interface $1
```

I'm running Monterey 12.2.1

Comment: Which instructions are you following here? AFAIK there is no PPTP support since macOS Sierra.

Comment: Was mainly following this article: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/PPP-HOWTO/x1455.html and other articles like this: https://gist.github.com/GabLeRoux/c7d4c9046d9b5ec7bce822426613912a. Do you happen to know if there is an 'official' statement about this that it's discontinued from Sierra?

Comment: The L in tldp stands for Linux :-) The gist implies that it should work, I assume you did try running the file manually to see whether it is executable etc.?

Comment: yep it works if I execute it manually.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to add certain subnets to my route table

When configuring IKEv2, Mac OS always waits for a subnet from the server.

For example:

- In older versions of [Strongswan](https://docs.strongswan.org/docs/5.9/howtos/forwarding.html#_split_tunneling_with_ikev2), you need to configure
  leftsubnet=<Your network(s)>.
- As far as I know, the new ones need to    change the parameter
  local_ts=<Your network(s)>

Also, to connect Mac OS via IKEv2, it is best to create a connection profile through [Apple Configurator](https://support.apple.com/apple-configurator).